# Detecting if Voxel or voxel group is still connected to rest of object

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine, path, physics, voxel

So I am building a voxel-based physics simulator in which voxels can be destroyed. Every voxelized object has a kind of "center voxel" to describe it, ill call it "peace A".
 All voxels are simulated as one until they are separated from  "peace A" or another voxel attached to it, then they(and/or other voxels connected to that voxel) get put into a new object with its own simulated physics. And here lies my problem, How Do I check if the voxel is still attached? in the most efficient way possible?
 pathfinding sounds like it would slow down allot when I scale up but happy to try and figure that out if its the best option. and updating all voxels at once when one voxel is destroyed doesn't sound too good either. Any of you geniuses have any ideas?

here are some drawings for clarity(ps please excuse my bad mouse-handwriting)

first image, with voxels still connected:
 [image: img]

second image, when the voxels separate:
 [image: img]

Comment: 3D floodfill? A* pathfinding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segmentation/labeling is the way (similar to raster A* and flood fill).

1. **for each voxel add a flag variable/space**

   this flag will be used to tell if voxel is used or not ... and can be used latter as a temp value...
2. **clear all flags to zero and set actual object `ID=1`.**
3. **pick first voxel with `flag=0`**
4. **flood fill it with actual object `ID`**

   so using 6 or 26  connectivity (analogy to 4 or 8 connectivity in 2D) flood fill the voxel flags with ID.
5. **increment `ID` and goto #3**

   stop when there are no more voxels with `flag=0`

After this the flag holds the sub object ID your original object is split into and `ID` holds the count of your new objects+1.

**[edit1] C++/VCL/OpenGL example**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit1.h"
#include "gl_simple.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const int n=16;     // voxel map resolution
bool map[n][n][n];  // voxel map
int  flg[n][n][n];  // (flag)
int pal[]=          // 0xAABBGGRR
    {
    0x007F0000,
    0x00007F00,
    0x0000007F,
    0x00007F7F,
    0x007F007F,
    0x007F7F00,
    0x00FF0000,
    0x0000FF00,
    0x000000FF,
    0x0000FFFF,
    0x00FF00FF,
    0x00FFFF00,
    };
const int pals=sizeof(pal)/sizeof(pals);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void fill(int x,int y,int z,int id)
    {
    // inside map check
    if ((x<0)||(x>=n)) return;
    if ((y<0)||(y>=n)) return;
    if ((z<0)||(z>=n)) return;
    // is it active voxel?
    if (!map[x][y][z]) return;
    // already filled with the same id?
    if (flg[x][y][z]==id) return;
    // set flag
    flg[x][y][z]=id;
    // fill neighbors
    fill(x-1,y,z,id);
    fill(x+1,y,z,id);
    fill(x,y-1,z,id);
    fill(x,y+1,z,id);
    fill(x,y,z-1,id);
    fill(x,y,z+1,id);
    fill(x-1,y-1,z,id);
    fill(x-1,y+1,z,id);
    fill(x+1,y-1,z,id);
    fill(x+1,y+1,z,id);
    fill(x-1,y,z-1,id);
    fill(x-1,y,z+1,id);
    fill(x+1,y,z-1,id);
    fill(x+1,y,z+1,id);
    fill(x,y-1,z-1,id);
    fill(x,y-1,z+1,id);
    fill(x,y+1,z-1,id);
    fill(x,y+1,z+1,id);
    fill(x-1,y-1,z-1,id);
    fill(x-1,y-1,z+1,id);
    fill(x-1,y+1,z-1,id);
    fill(x-1,y+1,z+1,id);
    fill(x+1,y-1,z-1,id);
    fill(x+1,y-1,z+1,id);
    fill(x+1,y+1,z-1,id);
    fill(x+1,y+1,z+1,id);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void recolor()
    {
    int x,y,z,id;
    // clear all flags to zero and set actual object ID=1
    id=1;
    for (x=0;x<n;x++)
     for (y=0;y<n;y++)
      for (z=0;z<n;z++)
       flg[x][y][z]=0;
    // pick first voxel with flag=0
    for (x=0;x<n;x++)
     for (y=0;y<n;y++)
      for (z=0;z<n;z++)
       if (map[x][y][z])
        if (flg[x][y][z]==0)
            {
            // flood fill it with actual object ID
            fill(x,y,z,id);
            // increment ID and goto #3
            id++;
            }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void TForm1::draw()
    {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    // center the view around map[][][]
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-80.0);
    glRotatef( 15.0,1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glTranslatef(-n,-n,-n);

    // render map[][][] as cubes (very slow old api version for simplicity)
    int x,y,z,i;
    for (x=0;x<n;x++)
     for (y=0;y<n;y++)
      for (z=0;z<n;z++)
       if (map[x][y][z])
        {
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(x+x,y+y,z+z);
        glColor4ubv((BYTE*)&(pal[flg[x][y][z]%pals]));
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        for (i=0;i<3*24;i+=3)
            {
            glNormal3fv(vao_nor+i);
            glVertex3fv(vao_pos+i);
            }
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();
        }

    glFlush();
    SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
    {
    gl_init(Handle);

    // init map[][][]
    int x,y,z,i0=2,i1=n-i0-1,xx,yy,zz;
    for (x=0;x<n;x++)
     for (y=0;y<n;y++)
      for (z=0;z<n;z++)
        {
        // clear map
        map[x][y][z]=false;
        // cube edges
        if (((x>=i0)&&(x<=i1))&&((y==i0)||(y==i1))&&((z==i0)||(z==i1))) map[x][y][z]=true;
        if (((y>=i0)&&(y<=i1))&&((x==i0)||(x==i1))&&((z==i0)||(z==i1))) map[x][y][z]=true;
        if (((z>=i0)&&(z<=i1))&&((x==i0)||(x==i1))&&((y==i0)||(y==i1))) map[x][y][z]=true;
        // ball
        xx=x-8; xx*=xx;
        yy=y-8; yy*=yy;
        zz=z-8; zz*=zz;
        if (xx+yy+zz<=16) map[x][y][z]=true;
        // X
        if ((y==i0)&&(x==  z  )&&(x>=4)&&(x<12)) map[x][y][z]=true;
        if ((y==i0)&&(x==n-z-1)&&(x>=4)&&(x<12)) map[x][y][z]=true;
        }
     recolor();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_exit();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_resize(ClientWidth,ClientHeight);
    draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
    {
    draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)
    {
    draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can ignore the **VCL** stuff and also the **OpenGL** rendering The only important stuff is on the top of the code up to (including) function `void recolor();` The `map` holds the individual voxels of our input map (hardcoded in my apps constructor with few objects). The `flg` array holds the `id` of object the corresponding voxel was labeled with (enumerated) and its used later for coloring each object with different color from the palette `pal[]`. To keep this as simple as I could I did not do any optimization (the fill and render are very slow because of that and can  be optimized **a lot**).

Here preview (after calling the `recolor()`):

[image: preview]

As you can see all the voxels connected share the same color which means they have the same `id` number in `flg` array (belong to same object) so the algo and code works as expected.

In case you want to use this the `gl_simple.h` is in here:

- [complete GL+GLSL+VAO/VBO C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214)

so you just need to port the **VCL** events into your environment style...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! yes this seems like a good solution, i will trigger this loop the moment an object gets destroyed and it should work fine! i will also experiment with running your system backwards so to speak, so it will fill from the recently dis-neighboured voxel and stop when it finds peace A maybe making it more efficient? thanks again :)

Comment: sorry for necromancing the threat, but  could you explain the process in betters terms? I'm trying to follow along the explanation, but I got lost through the vagueness. @Spektre

Comment: @Spektre Im just referring to the steps required to pull it off. You gave an excellent list, but its gets a bit vague. You say to give every voxel a child variable. Then set their child variable to 0, but also set their id to 1? what is Id? where does this come from? what is "actual object?" then it goes on; then you start your loop by finding the first block that still has 0 as their variable. that makes sense to begin the path, but then "flood fill with actual object id" so you fill the variable with the id of the block its dependant on? how would it know to switch dependents then?

Comment: @AlecHarvey I added some code I just busted together ...

Comment: @Spektre thanks, but I never used C++ before, so this is like an alien language to me. I was hoping for a more thorough list like a flowchart to explain the algorithm. Sorry that I was vague myself and wasted your time :(

Comment: @AlecHarvey ok: `flag` is a child variable to each voxel but `id` is just a single local variable used during the process of labeling objects.  It simply iterates from 1 upwards and it assigns found object unique number so each object in map will have different one. The actual object is the one that is found by the search for non labeled set voxel once found you fill all the connected voxels position with the `id` value and increment `id` so next object is labeled with different `id`.

Comment: @Spektre To me, that sounds like a very complex way of detecting all the blocks to be worked with. However, im not seeing/understanding how the blocks know to be dependent on one another or how they would know they are connected

Comment: @Spektre I imagine flood fill is just a complex iteration loop that allows iteration over 3d planes. That, I can somewhat get. but I do not know how the logic would work for the pathfinding between the outermost voxel knowing how its connected to the core voxel.

Comment: @AlecHarvey the flood fill **fills all the connected voxels** with id which is `1` for the first object then it is inceremnted to 2 so when next not yet filled voxel is found it is filled with 2... the next with 3 and so on until all objects are filled. So after that all voxels have the flag value filled with id of object they belong to. So in respect to OP question after destroying some voxel and doing the labeling again if the neigbor positions to destroed voxel have different flag numbers it means the object was disected ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227483/discussion-between-alec-harvey-and-spektre).

Answer (score 0):

1. Pick a random, not connected, object
2. Recursively get the up/down/left/right object till there is no left (always checking if the object is already connected)
3. If there are no objects left in the scene that are not connected, stop
4. Go to Step 1